# Data inconsistency in the Google+ Hangout App shared data object?

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I'm getting inconsistent results when setting and getting values using submitDelta, setValue, clearValue, and getState. It appears that these are asynchronous methods, so my synchronous commands (e.g., console.log) execute using a local data object. Then eventually the shared data object updates and in turn updates the local data object. Is this a correct assessment? Is there a way to run these data commands synchronously, i.e., wait for the shared data object to update before moving on in the program?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data operations in the Hangouts API are asynchronous. To achieve synchronicity you would have to listen to [`onStateChanged events`](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data.html#gapi.hangout.data.onStateChanged) and only continue whatever you are doing in those events.

The event will be called for all participants, also the local participant that triggered the change.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look possible to write synchronous shared data object calls because if you have more than one *onStateChange* in your code, they all fire together. In other words, I can't tie one shared data object update to one *onStateChange*.

It looks like Google+ Hangouts executes database APIs in this order:

1. Getting and setting values in the local data object (using *getState*)
2. Getting values from the shared data object using *getState*.
3. Changing values in the shared data object (*setValue*, *clearValue*, *submitDelta*, etc.).
4. *onStateChange* to listen for shared data object changes.

The following (pseudo)code

```
setValue('counter', '11')
getValue('counter')
onStateChanged (getValue('counter'))

submitDelta( {'counter': '22'} )
getValue('counter')
onStateChanged (getValue('counter'))

clearValue('counter')
getValue('counter')
onStateChanged (getValue('counter'))

submitDelta( {'counter': '33'} )
getValue('counter')
onStateChanged (getValue('counter'))
```

would return

`undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33
33`

because the four *getValue*s execute first, then *setValue*, *submitDelta*, *clearValue*, and *submitDelta* execute, then the four *onStateChanged* execute together, four times each because the shared data object is changed four times.

Does that sound right?